# How to remove a custom action on child theme?

Tags: actions

On parent theme `index.php` i have this code:

```
// The function.
add_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_example_function' );
function mytheme_example_function() {
    echo 'Example text on index page.'
}

// After function was defined i do the action.
do_action( 'mytheme_example_action' );
```

On child theme `functions.php` i have this code:

```
// Example 1 (not working).
add_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_remove_parent_function', 20);
function mytheme_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_example_function' );
}

// Example 2 (not working).
remove_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_example_function' );
```

I have tried both examples, still the echoed text `'Example text on index page.'` is showing on browser.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

1. For removing an action hook use the same *action name*, *callback name* and *priority* that was used to add a action in parent theme.
2. You should move the function from being defined in `index.php` to `functions.php` of the parent theme.
3. Lastly, you could register the child function using `init`.

So you end up with something like this:

---

#### Parent Theme Code

`functions.php`

```
// The function.
add_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_example_function' );
function mytheme_example_function() {
    echo 'Example text on index page.';
}
```

---

#### Child Theme Code

`functions.php`

```
// Example 1
add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_remove_parent_function');
function mytheme_remove_parent_function() {
     remove_action( 'mytheme_example_action', 'mytheme_example_function' );
}
```

---

#### Final Notes

[Here's a great tutorial](https://www.mhthemes.com/support/overriding-parent-theme-functions-child-theme-tutorial/) that'll show you a couple methods of achieving your desired outcome.